# Por que e quando usar enum em Java?

Tags: java, enums

Alguém que esteja a aprender a linguagem, novato ou experiente, pode nunca se ter cruzado com enumerações de Java. Já li por várias vezes que são úteis, por exemplo, para implementar os padrões *singleton* com mais garantias de visibilidade entre threads.

Qual é a utilidade de se aprender e usar as `enum` na programação do dia-a-dia?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As `enum` representam um conjunto fixo de valores, de uma forma mais ou menos *autodocumentada*. Tornam o código mais explícito, mais legível, e menos vulnerável a erros de programação.

Uma alternativa comum, é usar-se `String` ou `int` para valores constantes. As `enum` trazem algumas vantagens em relação a estes tipos:

- O compilador não permite erros tipográficos, como podem acontecer com literais de strings.
- O compilador não permite valores que estejam fora do conjunto enumerado, que é uma consequência das enumerações serem **tipos** elas próprias.
- Não é necessário escrever **pré-condições**, ou testes manuais, para assegurar que o argumento de um método está dentro da gama de valores aceite.
- O **invariante de tipo** é gratuito, novamente porque as enumerações são tipos, e definem à partida os valores válidos.
- Enumerações podem definir **comportamento** (métodos) para as suas constantes, como em qualquer classe habitual.
- As constantes de uma enumeração podem especializar o seu comportamento: cada constante pode ter a sua própria definição de um método.
- A máquina virtual dá garantias de *thread safety* ao carregar a enumeração.
- Podem igualmente ser usadas em `switch`.

Há ainda alguns usos criativos das enumerações, como por exemplo máquinas de estados, como visto [neste blog](http://vanillajava.blogspot.pt/2011/06/java-secret-using-enum-as-state-machine.html).

---

Vejamos um exemplo prático destas vantagens. Imagine um programa que recebe duas cores e tenta combiná-las, de acordo com o sistema RGB.

### Utilizando `int`

```
public static final int
    VERMELHO    = 1,
    AZUL        = 2,
    VERDE       = 4,
    AMARELO     = 5,
    CIANO       = 6,
    ROXO        = 3,
    BRANCO      = 7;

/**
 * @pre cor1 == VERMELHO || cor1 == AZUL || cor1 == VERDE ||
 *    cor1 == CIANO || cor1 == AMARELO || cor1 == ROXO || cor1 == BRANCO;
 * @pre cor2 == VERMELHO || cor2 == AZUL || cor2 == VERDE ||
 *    cor2 == CIANO || cor2 == AMARELO || cor2 == ROXO || cor2 == BRANCO;
 * @post cor1 == VERMELHO && cor2 == VERDE => return == AMARELO;
 * @post ...
 */
public static int combina(int cor1, int cor2) {
    if (!corValida(cor1)) return -1;
    if (!corValida(cor2)) return -1;
    return cor1 | cor2;
}

private boolean corValida(int cor) {
    return cor == VERMELHO || cor == VERDE || cor == AZUL ||
        cor == AMARELO || cor == CIANO || cor == ROXO || cor == BRANCO;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cor = combina(1, 2);
    // O que acontece quando VERMELHO e AZUL deixam de ser 1 ou 2?
    assert cor == ROXO;
}
```

### Utilizando `enum`

```
/*
 * Os codigos numéricos não fazem qualquer falta.
 * Seria possível resolver com switch, mas ficaria muito extenso para exemplo.
 * Contudo, um caso real deveria retirar os códigos,
 * para maiores garantias de que não há erro humano.
 */
public static enum Cor {
    VERMELHO(1), AZUL(2), VERDE(4), AMARELO(5), CIANO(6), ROXO(3), BRANCO(7);
    private final int codigo;

    Cor(int codigo) { this.codigo = codigo; }

    int codigo() { return codigo; }

    public static Cor porCodigo(int codigo) {
        for (Cor cor: Cor.values()) {
            if (codigo == cor.codigo()) return cor;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("codigo invalido");
    }
}

/**
 * @pre cor1 != null && cor2 != null;
 * @post cor1 == Cor.VERMELHO && cor2 == Cor.VERDE => return == Cor.AMARELO;
 * @post ...
 */
public static int combina(Cor cor1, Cor cor2) {
    int combinado = cor1.codigo() | cor2.codigo();
    return Cor.porCodigo(combinado);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cor cor = combina(Cor.VERMELHO, Cor.AZUL);
    assert cor == Cor.ROXO;
}
```

Comment: Gostei muito da resposta! Porém, considerando que ela faz uma pergunta do ponto de vista de alguém que é iniciante na linguagem, acho que seria interessante adicionar alguns exemplos de código. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Muito obrigado pela dica! Adicionei um exemplo usando `int` e o mesmo exemplo com `enum`, para marcar a diferença entre ambos. :)